# How to import big databases in R?

Tags: r, ram

I am trying to import a big database (80mb aprox) in .txt format with Rstudio.

I have tried using the "big memory"/"biganalytics"/"bigtabulate" libraries but gets the error of "R Session Aborted" after importing.

```
read.big.matrix("C:/data.txt", 
                type = "integer", 
                header = TRUE,
                backingfile = "x", 
                descriptorfile = "y",
                extraCols = NULL)
```

Any idea?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That's not that big; have you tried using `read.table`?

Comment: Unless this is a typo and you mean 80gb, that's quite the opposite of big.

Comment: Assuming you mean 80gb as @Roland suggests, you may want to have a look at the disk.frame package. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/disk.frame/versions/0.6.1

Comment: As DJ suggests, `disk.frame` is specifically designed for handling out-of-memory datasets, the `big*` libraries should handle it fine as well, however and I'm surprised you are experiencing issues there. In general once you reach a size where memory does not suffice, everything becomes more complicated, libraries that are built to handle these do not "Load" the entire dataset, but rather keep them on disk (and are thus slower). Another "solution" would be "buy a cloud server with enough memory".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to import a big database (80mb aprox) in .txt format with Rstudio.

80Mb is not a big file.

I assume that you mean 80Gb. If so then I would suggest running the workload on a computer with more resources (ie RAM). These days with the easy availability of scalable cloud resources such as AWS, GCP and Azure, this is very easy to do.

On the other hand if you are forced to use a machine with insufficient RAM then you can try to use an R package that keeps part of the data in RAM and part on disk. Obviously this results in performance degradation compared to everything being in RAM. One such package is `disk.frame`:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/disk.frame/versions/0.7.1